# Application crashes on update from app store

Tags: ios, crash, app-store

I have a app working fine and it is already submitted to app store. Now the problem comes in when the users of my app try to update the app with the latest version from the app store. The app crashes at splash screen.
If they delete the old version and make a fresh download then it does not pose any problem.
So what could be the factors causing this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you changed between the two versions?

Comment: What do you get when you try this yourself? Download the app onto your iPhone from the app store, run it, and then run the new version from XCode - what does the console show? Without any more information we can't help you; there's so many possibilities!

Answer (score 1):

Do you use `CoreData` in your project?

If yes, did you make any changes to database model?

If yes, did you make new version of database model?

If you didn't create new version of database model but just modify first version then it causes crash.

-> Check there crash logs

Comment: Independently the latest code is working fine. It only crashes when the old version is updated. And I haven't made any changes to database model in new version.

Comment: Did you try to install old version on your device and launch new version through Xcode? What is written in the crash log?